# How do I trim the middle part of a video in Photo Booth?

Tags: video, video-editing, photo-booth

I want to save the beginning and end portions of a Photo Booth video for export.
In other words, I don't want the middle part.
However, Photo Booth seems to only let me select a single portion to save - beginning, end or middle.

Edit: I ended up selecting the beginning, exporting, reverting the trim and selecting the end, then exporting again.
A decent stopgap for me, but obviously not a complete solution since this creates two files, so I won't add this as an answer.

Comment: Does the editing have to be done in Photo Booth, or is QuickTime an option?  There you could "split clip" twice and delete the middle.